# How many number of times application instance certificates are to be validated in OPC UA?

Tags: opc-ua, milo

Requesting a clarification on the number of times application instance certificates (both client/server) are validated from opening a SecureChannel to activating a Session in OPC UA security architecture ?

- From the book, 'OPC Unified Architecture' by Mahnke, Leitner, Damm, the following image is seen where the application instance certificates are seen validated. (Figure 7.4 in page no. 214)
  [image: Creating an OPC UA Secure Channel]
- According to the specification Part 4 Services, section 6.1.5 - figure 22 shows that the application instance certificates are validated again during the session creation.

Why is this difference between the standard and the concept described in the book ?
Is it really necessary to validate the application instance certificate again during session creation ? I notice that the Milo examples validate only once while opening a SecureChannel if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that diagram is incorrect or out of date.

Validation and verification of trust has to happen the first time client/server see the certificate, which is when the channels are established.

In Create/Activate Session service possession of the certificates is proved using the signatures exchanged in the requests/responses.

edit: to summarize the comments, validation needs to occur during session creation only if the transport layer being used doesn't validate it there, but in Milo's case it's always the binary TCP transport so validation during session creation is redundant.

Comment: Thank you for the immediate response. Just for my clarification, you mean the diagram in the specification is incorrect or out of date ? To add to this point, the Prosys examples are validating the application instance certificates again while creating a session.

Comment: Yeah, the above diagram may be out of date or a suggestion. It might also be necessary to validate in CreateSession if the transport is HTTPS instead of TCP, but I'm not sure. There's no reason to do validation twice though.

Comment: I'm going to check with some of the other working group members to see if validation is really supposed to occur a second time during session creation.

Comment: Thanks again. It would be great if you can clarify it. For a clarification, the image seen attached in the question is from the book and I think it makes sense because it shows the certificate validation while opening a secure channel. The Part 4 Services, standard specification is where the images are seen with certificate validation while session establishment. And yes, certificate validation is necessary during session establishment if it is a HTTPS connection.

Comment: I have confirmed, validation during session creation is only needed when the transport is HTTPS/WSS, in which case it does not happen at the secure channel layer. Milo does not support anything but the TCP transport right now, so the the validation only needs to occur the one time at the secure channel layer.

Comment: Kindly check the following answer where it states that the certificate validation is required in the session creation also and please clarify the same if possible.

Comment: I'm adding validation and trust chain verification to the session creation steps as well, in case Milo implements a transport that requires it some time in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The specification (OPC UA Spec. Part 4. 6.1 Security (v.1.03)) indeed specifies two phases which take part in the certificate validation:

1. Creating a SecureChannel and
2. Creating a Session.

In SecureChannel creation the certificates are validated for CA signature, the issue and expiry date and against revocation lists. At Session creation, a complete verification can be made.

The main difference is that the ApplicationDescriptions are available in the CreateSession phase and therefore the ApplicationUri field of the certificate can only be validated in this phase.

Comment: Thank you for highlighting this point. As exactly in my original question (2nd bulletin point) I was referring  to the same. It was not clear to me if the certificates are just used for challenge-response-test or they are validated completely again according to certificate validation steps. So it means the certificate URI (this check error cant be suppressed) can be validated only during session creation and this is the only step of validation that is executed during the session creation ? or all the other steps of validation are also executed ? @Kevin Herron